# Как вырезать первый элемент массива через Reduce?

Tags: javascript

Почему консоль лог возвращает ["Москва" ,"Смоленск"]
Нужно из каждого массива удалить первый элемент и соединить их.

```js
let list = [
  ['Иван', 'Москва', 'Питер', 'Нижний'],
  ['Петр', 'Можайск', 'Смоленск'],
  ['Саша', 'Москва', 'Смоленск']
];

let city = list.reduce((acc,val) => {
  val.shift();
  return val;
});

console.log(city);
```

Comment: какой конечный результат ожидается, для текущего примера?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать map в данном случае.

И в данном случае лучше подойдет `slice(1)` чем `shift`, так как `shift` изменяет исходный массив

Для того чтобы преобразовать массив в "одномерный" можно воспользоваться методом `flat()`

```js
let list = [
  ['Иван', 'Москва', 'Питер', 'Нижний'],
  ['Петр', 'Можайск', 'Смоленск'],
  ['Саша', 'Москва', 'Смоленск']
];

let city = list.map(val => val.slice(1)).flat(1)

console.log('city', city);
console.log('list', list);
```

Можете почитать как работает `reduce`:

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

[Как работает reduce()](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-reduce-%D0%B2-javascript-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-b650c397bee6)

Comment: а можно узнать почему?

Comment: Поправил ответ, а каким образом вам тут поможет reduce?

Comment: Я вообще думал, что метод Reduce обратиться к каждому массиву внутри основного и запишет его

Comment: типа так let city = list.reduce((acc,val) => {
  val.shift();
  return acc.concat(val);
}, []);

Comment: Метод reduce обычно используется для работы с числами, например подсчитать сумму, среднее и тд, хотя бы потому что у него первый параметр в коллбеке это accumulator, который накапливает значения, зачем же тогда использовать его в таком случае, когда работаете со строками, точнее даже с массивами? Есть метод map который идеально подходит в данном случае, ну хотите возьмите forEach. Вам же нужно изменить массив, это предназначение метода map. Разве ваш код с reduce отображет то что выполняет? Использовать reduce таким образом семантически неверно

Comment: а как тогда при использовании мак лучше объединить все массивы в 1

Comment: Поправил ответ, я изначально не понял каким образом должен выглядеть преобразованный массив, поэтому советую в вопросе указывать каким образом вы хотите видеть результат

Comment: _Вам же нужно изменить массив, это предназначение метода map._ - это совсем не предназначение `map`

Comment: _Метод reduce обычно используется потому что у него первый параметр в коллбеке это accumulator, который накапливает значения, зачем же тогда использовать его в таком случае, когда работаете со строками, точнее даже с массивами?_ - как раз потому, что он может накапливать результат в аккумулятор.

Answer (score 2):

Результатом метода [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), является значение, которое было возвращено на последней итерации.

В данном случае, это `['Саша', 'Москва', 'Смоленск']`  без первого элемента, так как на каждой итерации, вместо аккумулятора возвращается значение текущего элемента

Вместо этого, необходимо было использовать `acc`, в котором содержится значение с предыдущей итерации.

Так как это массив - для объединения достаточно использовать метод [`.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

```js
let list = [
  ['Иван', 'Москва', 'Питер', 'Нижний'],
  ['Петр', 'Можайск', 'Смоленск'],
  ['Саша', 'Москва', 'Смоленск']
];

let city = list.reduce((acc, val) => {
  return acc.concat(val.slice(1));
}, []);

console.log(city);
```

Альтернативным решением может быть использование метода [`.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
let list = [
  ['Иван', 'Москва', 'Питер', 'Нижний'],
  ['Петр', 'Можайск', 'Смоленск'],
  ['Саша', 'Москва', 'Смоленск']
];

let city = list.flatMap((val) => val.slice(1));

console.log(city);
```

Comment: Отлично! Кажется, что все новинки проштудировал, но нет... Вот, _flatMap_ для меня открыли. Спасибо.